# Eclipse RCP application Active Title Bar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working in an RCP application similar to Eclipse where the user can navigate in Project Explorer tree and opens any file in the Editor

i am Setting the RCP application title in a class which extends "**WorkbenchWindowAdvisor**" as the following:

> ```
>   IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
>   configurer.setTitle("My RCP Application title");
> ```

But what i need to show up in title bar **the perspective name and the opened file path** like in normal eclipse:

[image: Image of Eclipse title bar showing perspective and recent opened file name]

any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is requires listening to a lot of events in your WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.

In the `preWindowOpen` method you need to add listeners for:

- Page activation and closing using `configurer.getWindow().addPageListener(listener)` The `pageActivated` and `pageClosed` listener methods need to update the title.
- Perspective changes using `configurer.getWindow().addPerspectiveListener(listener)`. The `perspectiveActivated`, `perspectiveSavedAs`, `perspectiveDeactivated` methods need to update the title.
- Part activations using `configurer.getWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(listener)`. This need to use an `IPartListener2`. The `partActivated`, `partBroughtToTop`, `partClosed`, `partHidden`, `partVisible` methods need to update the title.

You get the open file path from the active editor:

```
IWorkbenchPage currentPage = configurer.getWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart activeEditor = currentPage.getActiveEditor();
if (activeEditor != null) {
   path = activeEditor.getTitleToolTip();
}
```

and the perspective name:

```
IPerspectiveDescriptor persp = currentPage.getPerspective();
if (persp != null) {
    label = persp.getLabel();
}
```

The full, even more complex, code for this is in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`

Comment: It Works (Y) !
Many Thanks